# Different forms of using 'let'

Tags: javascript

I saw a tutorial for JavaScript ES6 in which the guy used this syntax to assign a value with `let`:

```
let = name = ['Jhon','Paul','Ean']
```

What is the difference between the first and this:

```
let name = ['Jhon','Paul','Ean']
```

Comment: Very related: [Why is assigning a value to the variable “let” possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45521283/3853934)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- The first one is creating two global variables: `let` and `name`, and
  assigning the array first to `name` and then to `let`. It is not what
  you want for sure.
- The second one creates a block scope local variable called `name`. This
  is the one you want!