# Why is assigning a value to the variable "let" possible?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, let

I am taking an online JS course and the instructor used the syntax : `let = names = ["Bob","Tim","Larry"]`.  I am convinced that was an accident, but somehow allowed by the JS environment he was using.  What he ended up doing (probably by accident) was assign the array to the "names" variable, which assigned it to the "let" variable.

My question: why is this not an error?  Why can "let" be used as an variable? We know "let" is a keyword. Or is it just something they haven't outlawed yet?  You can still do it in the Chrome and Firefox console... and in Node, too, for that matter.

Comment: Interesting point. `let=123` is allowed and will create a global scope variable with the value 123, but `var=123` will raise an error.

Comment: In the environment where `let=123` works, does `let foo = 123`; also work?  Can you do both in the same script?

Comment: For some reason they did not include it in the list of reserved keywords. You can actually even do `var let = 'something'` and it works, however to avoid the first issue (accidentally assigning a global variable instead of initializing an array called names, you can add `'use strict'` to the beginning of your script.

Comment: @JeffUK I do not think that would work in any environment, since pre-let browsers would throw unexpected identifier and ES6 compatible ones would throw unexpected number, because without `=` it tries to decalre a variable.

Comment: As `let` was only recently introduced into JavaScript, it would have been a dangerous step to make the use of ` let` as a variable name illegal. This might cause problems with legacy code.

Comment: @cars10m why is "const" illegal then? couldn't that have also been used in legacy code? Or was that always illegal?

Comment: I don't know ;-) to be honest. But then again... in JavaScript it has always been legal to assign any variable even without declaring it at all, thereby generation global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES3 and earlier JavaScript versions, `let` didn't have any special meaning and could be used as an identifier. `const`, however, was already on the list of future reserved words. See http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf, **7.5.1
Reserved Words**.

ES5 added "strict mode". `const` is still on the list of future reserved words and `let` is to be treated like a future reserved word in strict mode: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-7.6.1

ES6 gave a meaning to `const` and `let`, but `let` is still not a reserved word. Instead it says in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords:

> In [strict mode code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code), `let` and `static` are treated as reserved keywords through static semantic restrictions (see [12.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-early-errors), [13.3.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors), [13.7.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-static-semantics-early-errors), and [14.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors)) rather than the lexical grammar.

In other words, outside of strict mode, you can use `let` both as a variable name and to declare other variables.

The reason `let` wasn't made into a reserved word is probably to not break existing code that may have used `let` as a normal identifier.

Answer (score 2):

It is not on the list of preserved keywords as of the version of EcmaScript your browser is implementing, due to backwards compatibility concerns. You can opt out of this behaviour by using the `'use strict'` inside your `.js` document in modern browsers. As for a list of what keywords are to be reserved in the future but are most likely to still not be reserved in today's browsers, take a look at this list: [JavaScript List of Reserved Keywords](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). Notice that the ones marked with `*` are ES5 - ES6 specific keywords, which means that those are likely to be added to the actual list at a later point.

Notice that `const` was added at an earlier stage and thus it is a reserved keyword today and is implemented correctly.